# Showing that a sequence of compact operators converge uniformly to their pointwise limit

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, uniform-convergence, compact-operators

I am working out of Phillipe G. Ciarlet's *Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis with Applications* and am struggling with exercise 4.9-5. The problem is as follows: Let $G$ be a function in the space $L^2([0,1]\times [0,1])$. Given any function $f\in L^2(0,1)$, let
$$
Af(x) := \int_0^1 G(x,\xi) f(\xi) d\xi, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1.
$$
Show that this relation defines a function $Af\in L^2(0,1)$, and that the linear operator $A:L^2(0,1) \to L^2(0,1)$ defined in this fashion is compact.

Ciarlet gives a hint of how to proceed, and suggests we use the theorem below.

**Theorem**: If $T_n:H\to H$ is a sequence of compact operators and $T_n$ converges uniformly to some $T$ in operator norm, then $T$ is compact.

**Here is my attempt**: Let $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2(0,1)$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $P_n$ be the continuous linear operator
$$
P_nf = P_n \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty (f, e_k ) e_k \right) =  \sum_{k=1}^n (f, e_k ) e_k.
$$
The image of each $P_n$ is finite dimensional, hence $P_n$ is compact for each $n$. Also, set $Q_n = I- P_n$ and $A_n = P_n A P_n$. Then we can write
\begin{align}
A - A_n = A - P_n A P_n &= 
(A Q_n + AP_n ) -  P_n A P_n \\ &=
AQ_n + (Q_n AP_n + P_nAP_n) -  P_n A P_n \\ &=
AQ_n + Q_n AP_n.
\end{align}
I had thought that this expression of $A - A_n$ would be helpful since $Q_n f \to 0$ for all  $f\in L^2(0,1)$, but I am struggling with using this to show uniform convergence. Does anyone have advice on how to proceed?

Comment: First you should prove that $\|T\|\le \|G\|_2.$ Next approximate in $L^2$ norm the function $G$ by functions $G_n$ which are finite linear combinations of $e_k(x)e_l(\xi)$. The corresponding operators $T_n$ are finite dimensional and $\|T_n-T\|\le \|G_n-G\|_2.$